# Chrome extension override

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension that I found online. I am trying to put a link to my website in the override file but I am unsure how to do it. If anyone would know how it would be greatly appreciated.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Cape Breton's Homepage</title>
</head>
<body>
script/code would go here
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why is this tagged `php`? Chrome extensions are written in JavaScript.

Comment: Sorry Im new to this

Comment: You need to spend enough hours learning how to build the extensions for Chrome. It is not that difficult. You need to simply understand how to make manifests permissions, menus perhaps. 
Then it will be very obvious where you want to put your link and how. Extension is great and very powerful tool.
As far as the snippet you provided goes:
You must treat anything that is displayed as a regular `HTML` thing. So a regular `<a>` tag must be used to create a link.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Cape Breton's Homepage</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <a href="https://yourwebsite.com">Your Website</a>
    </body>
    </html>
```